# mysql: show databases doesn't show any databases

Tags: mysql, database, show

I am new to using MySQL on a Mac. I am trying to show all the default databases but nothing is showing up when I use the command "show databases".

I have tried uppercase and lowercase. As well as using a semicolon and without it.

-> show databases 
    ->

SHOW DATABASES;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SHOW DATABASES' at line 2

I am trying to see the default databases in MySQL before proceeding

Comment: Did you login with a valid account that is allowed to do this

Comment: Try again with the semi-colon. From what it looks like here, your command is `show databases SHOW DATABASES;` so of course that's not going to work. There are very few commands that will work without a semi-colon; without it, it thinks you're going to continue the command on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

I was logged in as root user but getting same error, finally trying some combination found that in "Show DATABASES;" command  DATABASES part is case sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add ';' before ending the line.
-> show databases;

Best of Luck.

Comment: If there is any typo in the given code, please vote to close the question instead of answering it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34167775)

Answer (score -1):

Here you can type SHOW DATABASES;
SHOW & DATABASES both are case sensitive and do not forgot ; in last

Comment: If there is any typo in the given code, please vote to close the question instead of answering it. Also, are you sure that these queries **are** case sensitive?